# Whether can echart set height and width for label in markline, or add html tag and css attributes in formatter?

Tags: html, css, echarts

I want to custom height, width for markline info. Now, I find label attribute which can be used to color and font attriubtes. But for height and width, it don't work in my test.

I also want to add some html tags and css attributes in my formatter function. But it don't work too.

Any one can tell me whether echart current support these options?(echat is version 4.9.0)

Thanks

My info label for markline:

```
                label: {
                        show:true,
                        align:'left',
                        position: 'end',
                        distance: [0,-90],
                        color: 'blue',
                        // backgroundColor: 'green',
                        backgroundColor: {
                            image: 'icon/no_disturb.png'
                        },

                        padding: 15,

                        **
                        width:600,
                        height:900,
                         **
                        // borderRadius: 5,
                        formatter: function(value) {
                            return `2012年-10月-21日 5点43分24秒`;
                         }
                    }
```

my formatter function:

```
     formatter: function (param) {  
        var text = '';
        text += '<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">'+
                    '<div style="background-color:#03D16D;height:auto;width:10px;margin-right:5px;"></div>'+
                    '<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;">'+
                        '<span>'333'</span>'+
                        '<span>'333'</span>'
                    '</div>'
                '</div>'
       return text;
    }
```

```
or
```

```
   formatter: function (param) {    
    return `<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
                <div style="background-color:#03D16D;height:auto;width:10px;margin-right:5px;"></div>
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
                    <span>123</span>
                    <span>456</span>
                </div>
            </div>`
    }
```

these two functions just return a string and cannot be shown as a html section. I don't know how to do.

Thanks.

br

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's look like this. New label you can create with function `CustomLabel`:

```
label1 = new CustomLabel({
  chart: myChart,   // chart instance
  title: 'Label 1', // label title
  x: 'A2', y: 10    // coordinates
});
```

[image]

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

function CustomLabel(opts) {
  var {
    chart,
    title,
    x,
    y
  } = opts;
  var template = `<div class='label'>${name}</div>`;
  var canvas = document.body.querySelector('#main');
  var [chartX, chartY] = chart.convertToPixel({
    seriesIndex: 0
  }, [x, y]);
  var label = document.createElement('div');
  label.innerText = title;
  label.classList.add('label');
  label.style.left = chartX + 'px';
  label.style.top = chartY - 16 - 20 + 'px'; // 6 * 2 - paddings, 2 * 2 borders, 20 - height
  return canvas.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', label);
};

var option = {
  xAxis: {
    data: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"],
    splitLine: {
      show: true
    },
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    },
  },
  tooltip: {},
  yAxis: {},
  grid: {
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    right: 50
  },
  backgroundColor: '#7BE2DB',
  animation: false,
  series: [{
    name: 'Series1',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 15, 20],
    color: '#00B2A1',
  }]
};

myChart.setOption(option);

label1 = new CustomLabel({
  chart: myChart,
  title: 'Label 1',
  x: 'A2',
  y: 10
});
label2 = new CustomLabel({
  chart: myChart,
  title: 'Label 2',
  x: 'A5',
  y: 20
});
```

```css
#main {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #005C53;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.9.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 800px;height:600px;"></div>
```

Comment: hi, Sergey Fedorov, Thanks your help very much. I will try it.

Comment: hi, Sergey Fedorov. It is a great example and i don't know label can be shown like your code. Thanks.  I want to show data  label in xAxis just because default label don't mark at right place. Can i use custom label to show it? is there any other method? Thanks.

Comment: It's just plain JavaScript code which receives by Echarts API methods the Axes coordinates for calculate label position. You can may use it as you want and anywhere. The alternative solutions are much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, this is not a CSS, you cannot apply random style to label component. All [possible styles](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.markLine.label) described in official docs but we don't have many options. In particular, the label component will not be able to render HTML. I would help you, but it is not clear what you want to get: you described the process of gaining bad experience, but did not describe the desired result.

Just change width and height? It can be achieved with different ways. For example at yesterday due to the old version of the Echarts build, we had to completely [draw and animate markLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642677/echartshow-to-set-markline-lable-above-the-line-and-at-the-end-of-the-line/64761667) with labels. Also can add series line, set fake datapoints and do it in such a way that line will be straight and similar to markLine how we did do for [simulation confidence band](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724715/echarts-plot-the-variance-of-signals/61863485).

Comment: HI, Sergey Fedorov， thank your help very much. I just want to show information in markLine lable. (This information combinefrom different variable. line break is needed too. example: `ababab\n2012-10-21 5:43:24`, Data and ababab are variable.). I just find a link in github that label information can be customed. (link:https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/13269
)  By now, I  have to create a string in advance and just return in function formatter, just like below:         formatter: function (value) { return value.name}. It is better to support variable and line break. thanks.

Comment: HI, Sergey Fedorov, I also want to add a background image for markline lable. In a simple html page, below code can work:                    backgroundColor: { image: 'icon/no_disturb.png' }, icon is a sub directory. But in my vue project, I test many times with different directory, it always fails. I really don't know how to do it. If any advice, Please help me too. Thanks.

Comment: Add my label config:`{
          show: true,
          align: "left",
          position: "end",
          distance: [0, 4],
          color: "black",
          padding: 5,
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: {
             image: './images/f1.png'
          },
          shadowColor: srcBorderColor,
          shadowBlur: 1,
          shadowOffsetX: 1,
          shadowOffsetY: 1,

          backgroundColor: "white",

          formatter: function (value) {
            return value.name
          },
}`

Comment: @mmm2006, you config cannot be used, could you attach picture which shows as you label looks like?

Comment: I add a image but I cannot view it in my side. :(

Comment: hi, Sergey Fedorov, can you find my piacture?

Comment: Yes, see answer

Comment: HI, Sergey Fedorov, can you help me about this issue. Thanks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64869684/how-to-show-only-one-tooltip-in-a-connnted-echart-instances

Answer (score 0):

I add a picture about add label in xAxis to show accurate time label at my wanted position.

THanks.

[image]