# Format or styling label in apache echarts markLine

Tags: echarts

I need format label in the markline. Is possible add image backround, or in general custom styling?.

Is possible draw the markLine over the candles?, because at the moment when the markline goes down, the candles cover the label.

[image: number in the markLine label]

I would like to do something like what is shown this picture:

[image: label styling]

EDIT:
This is my actual code

```
            m.setOption(
            {
                series: {
                    markLine: {
                        symbol: 'none',
                        label:
                            {
                                position: 'middle',
                                show: true,
                            },
                        lineStyle: {
                            color: mc,
                            //type: 'solid'
                        },
                        data: [{yAxis: window.wsData[1], name: 'Tiker'}],
                        position: 'insideStartTop'
                    }
                }
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This labels has limit to improve deep custom design. By my opinion it's right decision because many developers don't understand design and other people will frustrate due incorrect style, color, position... But we are developers and no one can interfere with our love for real art, hehe )

Try to implement this options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64875984/1597964

Comment: Well, I will try.